# What technology is used to build "Visual Studio 11"?

Tags: microsoft, visual-studio

A preview of the new "Visual Studio 11" was recently shown at Microsoft's BUILD conference.

Out of interest, what technology is being used to create it?

I assume it's not WinRT (which I've been led to believe is only for Metro style apps in the new Windows 8 touch-first environment)

Is it still using WPF (like 2010)?

Is it built on .NET 4.5?

Are there any new technologies going into it?

Do we know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My best **guess** is it is still written using [the same technology as Visual Studio 2010](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/75322/which-language-was-used-to-create-visual-studio-2010/75323#75323).

Visual Studio 2010 was written in C#/WPF but most likely some C++ as well.

The demonstrations showed it didn't run in Metro Style (luckily), but it switched to the ordinary desktop environment which doesn't run on WinRT. Do note that [.NET 4.5 can/and should do WinRT calls](https://web.archive.org/web/20210926171917/https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-834T). I recall (can't verify this atm) that some parts of .NET 4.0 were dropped as they are now encompassed within WinRT.

Whether you need the .NET 4.5 runtime in order to run Visual Studio 2011 I don't know, but you could perhaps find out by installing [the developer preview](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119171039/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2011/09/14/announcing-visual-studio-11-developer-preview.aspx).